# Terraform - Deploying GCP Bucket With Multiple Storage Classes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform

According to the documentation (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html),

> the acceptable values for "storage_class" are: STANDARD,
> MULTI_REGIONAL, REGIONAL, NEARLINE, COLDLINE, ARCHIVE.

However, what if I want to deploy a GCP bucket that's REGIONAL and ARCHIVE?

I've tried:

```
storage_class = "ARCHIVE, REGIONAL"
```

And:

```
storage_class = "ARCHIVE", "REGIONAL"
```

Neither unfortunately work.
For the first, I receive the message:

> Argument definitions must be separated by newlines, not commas. An
> argument definition must end with a newline.

For the second, I receive the message:

> Invalid Value

Is it possible to define multiple storage classes for GCP buckets with Terraform?

Comment: I would imagine it's just not supported. Add a feature request onto the [provider github page](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage has four storage classes that is:

- Standard
- Nearline
- Coldline
- Archive

However, there are also [additional storage classes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#legacy) which cannot be created using GCP Console. This additional classes are also equivalent to Standard storage, except on how each objects are stored depending on the region.

It is a conflict to deploy a bucket that is both `REGIONAL` and `ARCHIVE` storage classes. According to the Cloud Storage documentation:

> **Regional Storage**: Equivalent to Standard Storage, except Regional Storage can only be used for objects stored in regions.

Comment: Yet it is: I've just tested this myself via the Cloud Console. The location type is set to "Region" and the default storage class is set to "Archive". This is what I want to achieve with Terraform.

Comment: Then you must be referring to "Region" as a location type rather than storage class. If that's the case, then specify your chosen region using [`location`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html#location) as demonstrated in this [example](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-cloud-storage/blob/master/examples/simple_bucket/main.tf). If you choose a specific region, then the location type of your bucket will be "Region".